# "Failed to lauch test" in Android console in Eclipse 4.3. Where to find what actually happened?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

When trying to run a class as an Android JUnit Test in Eclipse, I get the common 'Failed to lauch test' error. However, when trying to run a package as an Android JUnit Test in Eclipse, it works - which means I have everything configured correctly but there's an error in my CustomInstrumentationTestRunner. My question is: where can I find more detailed information on what happened rather than the uselessly vague 'Failed to lauch test'? Or at least the commands used to run my CustomInstrumentationTestRunner.

There is nothing in the logcat about starting any tests (but the logcat shows that the apks were indeed correctly installed) and no warnings or failures.
There are also zero warnings, failures or anything relevant to launching tests in Eclipse's log (.metadata/.log). My guess is that the issue is expressed somewhere in eclipse's ADT plugin. Where's its log? I've even grepped for 'Failed to' and 'lauch test' in Eclipse's .metadata folder and nothing. Argh. Where's the stack trace? GIVE. IT. TO. ME.... NOW.

This is the output in the Android console:

```
[2014-02-13 13:50:17 - test-project] ------------------------------
[2014-02-13 13:50:17 - test-project] Android Launch!
[2014-02-13 13:50:17 - test-project] adb is running normally.
[2014-02-13 13:50:17 - test-project] Performing android.test.CustomInstrumentationTestRunner JUnit launch
[2014-02-13 13:50:18 - test-project] Automatic Target Mode: using device '007bfc69d34ca4ee'
[2014-02-13 13:50:18 - test-project] Uploading test-project.apk onto device '007bfc69d34ca4ee'
[2014-02-13 13:50:18 - test-project] Installing test-project.apk...
[2014-02-13 13:50:24 - test-project] Success!
[2014-02-13 13:50:24 - test-project] Project dependency found, installing: project
[2014-02-13 13:50:24 - project] Uploading project.apk onto device '007bfc69d34ca4ee'
[2014-02-13 13:50:29 - project] Installing project.apk...
[2014-02-13 13:50:50 - project] Success!
[2014-02-13 13:50:50 - test-project] Launching instrumentation android.test.CustomInstrumentationTestRunner on 007bfc69d34ca4ee
[2014-02-13 13:50:50 - test-project] Failed to launch test
```

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any logs nor is there a stack trace :(. The exception is completely ignored.

The source is at: http://osxr.org/android/source/sdk/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt/src/com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/launch/junit/AndroidJUnitLaunchAction.java

Relevant section:

```
 /**
  * Launch a instrumentation test run on given Android device.
  * Reuses JDT JUnit launch delegate so results can be communicated back to JDT JUnit UI.
  * <p/>
  * Note: Must be executed on non-UI thread.
  *
  * @see IAndroidLaunchAction#doLaunchAction(DelayedLaunchInfo, IDevice)
  */
 @Override
 public boolean doLaunchAction(DelayedLaunchInfo info, IDevice device) {
     String msg = String.format(LaunchMessages.AndroidJUnitLaunchAction_LaunchInstr_2s,
             mLaunchInfo.getRunner(), device.getSerialNumber());
     AdtPlugin.printToConsole(info.getProject(), msg);

     try {
        mLaunchInfo.setDebugMode(info.isDebugMode());
        mLaunchInfo.setDevice(info.getDevice());
        JUnitLaunchDelegate junitDelegate = new JUnitLaunchDelegate(mLaunchInfo);
        final String mode = info.isDebugMode() ? ILaunchManager.DEBUG_MODE :
            ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE;

        junitDelegate.launch(info.getLaunch().getLaunchConfiguration(), mode, info.getLaunch(),
                info.getMonitor());

        // TODO: need to add AMReceiver-type functionality somewhere
     } catch (CoreException e) {
         AdtPlugin.printErrorToConsole(info.getProject(),
                 LaunchMessages.AndroidJUnitLaunchAction_LaunchFail);
     }
     return true;
 }
```